# Alternative method to download SAP Standard Fiori Apps

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I am aware of downloading standard SAP Fiori apps from ABAP Repository using the `/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD` program. Also, I understand that the apps may directly be imported into SAPUI5 Web IDE if connected to the SAP system.

I want to know if there is any other way to access Standard SAP Fiori Apps since I am required to work on extending standard apps but currently don't have an access to any SAP System.

Kindly help. Many thanks.

Comment: MAYBE, not quite sure, you can access SAP Demo System ES5 to retrieve a standard app or even develop against this system? https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/05/new-sap-gateway-demo-system-available/

Comment: Thank you @zYrEx for the suggestion. I added this system as a destination in my Web IDE but while trying to import standard applications, I am not able to find the ones I am looking for. Have you used this system by any chance, so you can tell me if standard Fiori apps are supposed to be present on ES5 system?

Comment: for which app are you looking? I did not try it myself, but options are limited without upload/download and a connection to a SAP system

Comment: I am looking for the following app - https://fioriappslibrary.hana.ondemand.com/sap/fix/externalViewer/#/detail/Apps('F0706')/S8OP

Comment: Also, I was not able to download apps from the SAPGUI for HTML (https://sapes5.sapdevcenter.com/sap/bc/gui/sap/its/webgui) of the ES5 system. When I try to download my required app using the '/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD' program, it does not allow me to select a local folder for saving the project.

Comment: yeah, it looks like the UI5 app "FIN_GL_LITB" is not available on this system. thats bad but was worth trying. You need to find someone having this package installed and can download you the app (SAP Fiori for SAP S/4HANA Finance 1605 SPS 4), I think no other options left...but still, you wouldnt see any data without having an odata connection.... not sure if you will achieve anything useful at the end only having the app.

Comment: Yes, it was totally worth trying. Thanks so much for the help. I'll update if anything else works!

Answer (score 1):

> but currently don't have an access to any SAP System

SAP does **not** provide source code of standard apps in public access, neither Fiori nor traditional app. If you have no access to S4HANA, then you are out of the luck.

The only option I can imagine is a [SAP CAL (Cloud Appliance Library)](https://cal.sap.com/) where you you can quickly deploy full-featured S4HANA, download your app and then terminate the instance. It wouldn't be very expensive for such short-time task.

Another possible option is to download software components related to your app (**UIAPFI70 400** + **S4CORE 101**) from [SAP Launchpad](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/softwarecenter/template/products/_APP=00200682500000001943&_EVENT=NEXT&HEADER=Y&FUNCTIONBAR=Y&EVENT=TREE&NE=NAVIGATE&ENR=73554900100800000266&V=INST&TA=ACTUAL/SAP%20S4HANA)  and try to dig into archives to pick out needed files manually, but for me it seems a dead end. Be aware, that your app is deprecated since 1709 and see [relevant note](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2058334).

P.S. BTW to download Fiori you can use not only `/UI5/UI5_REPOSITORY_LOAD` but also [Eclipse way](https://archive.sap.com/kmuuid2/309d2011-6579-3110-79b2-ec3259661c6d/Extending%20and%20Testing%20SAP%20Fiori%20Apps.pdf).